# Error when clicking calendar view for daily visits

Tags: bug, status-review, profile-page

When I click to view this it's loading and never show dates

[image]

I got some errors on the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: $cal.datepicker is not a function
    at Object.showCalendar (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:2651), <anonymous>:12:14)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:27449)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.min.js:2:27748)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:2651), <anonymous>:6:38)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:27449)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.min.js:2:27748)
    at n.fn.ready (jquery.min.js:2:29814)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2:25180)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2:406)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:2651), <anonymous>:5:5)
```

Is this problem on the Stack Overflow site or anything else?

Comment: I can [replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t4qx.gif) in FF 117.0 on Windows 10

Comment: I dunno about "ASAP"; of all the bugs I would put this as low priority (I'd much rather they fix the profile page so it doesn't take 25 seconds to load first...).

Comment: On MSE: [Visited Calendar pop out on user activity pages missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392624)

Comment: As a workaround, based on [the answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392883/271271) by [InSync](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1341484/insync), you can execute `delete $.ui` in the browser console *prior to trying to open the calendar* and have the calendar displayed normally.

Comment: I tried @Makyen but its not working

Comment: @Makyen it works, I tested on Firefox 118.0.1 Windows 11.

Comment: Still happening for me on Chrome v.117 on macOS 13.3 (Ventura)

Comment: Still happening on Chrome v118.0.5993.120, tho the workaround from @Makyen is working

Comment: Still am also facing this problem on Chrome, do we get any update?

Comment: @Makyen, please check this bug and fix it if possible.

Comment: @Shawn I'm unsure why you're pinging me about fixing it. I don't work for Stack Overflow and have no ability to make changes to the site's code.The most I can do is add the [meta-tag:status-review] tag (done), which creates a ticket in the company's system. A staff member should have then triaged that ticket and routed it to development as a bug report. The only other thing I can do is provide a work-around (done) and/or a userscript (I've added it to the userscript which is my personal, unreleased set of fixes/changes, but I don't plan to create a separate one and release it).

Comment: thanks a lot for your co operation. actually i dont know about yourself but i see you are *Mod* thats why pinging you btw hope SO will take an action about this. @Makyen

Comment: @Shawn see: [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: I have the same problem on Win11/Opera GX

Comment: The problem seems to have been fixed.  The calendar appears on all sites I regularly check, including SO.

Comment: yes @hardmath i just check this it was fixed atlast..

Comment: @Shawn:  Curiously the calendar is still broken on the Saves tab of the User page.  Also noted on the Meta SE version of this report.