# January 2024 post from Ryan Polk, Chief Product Officer

Tags: discussion, blog, announcement

Ryan Polk, our new(ish) Chief Product Officer, has published his [first blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/01/18/the-path-to-socially-responsible-ai/), which speaks to the path to socially responsible AI and his vision for the place that Stack Overflow has in that.  As always, we invite your comments and discussion, both on the blog post itself and also here.

Comment: *"Through the next year ... we’ll also be focusing on improving how users onboard, engage..."* does this mean that [so] is actually going to get the Staging Ground launched at something point this year?

Comment: It would be great if Ryan could actually share his vision for Stack Overflow and how to solve the actual issues plaguing the community instead of only talking about "AI"

Comment: "We believe AI has evolved from being a tool of developers to being a part of the community itself" - I don't think I've ever heard a single statement so out of touch with reality before

Comment: Also, what's up with the typography in this article? It goes from smart quotes to straight quotes to `"data ''` with two apostrophes and bad spacing back to smart quotes.

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike maybe they mean they want it to replace all the experts it can't keep engaged anymore... using stale 10 year old answers... what could go wrong

Comment: I also don't quite get where "responsibility" comes in. No one's being asked if they want their contributions to SO to be a part of this, at best this is referring to citing sources... but simply citing sources does nothing to verify their accuracy for usage today.

Comment: @KevinB I don't quite get where responsibility comes in when they threw all other projects under the bus to focus on pushing as many AI tools as possible, in the shortest period of time possible. The blog post is directly contradicted by their actions so far

Comment: I still don't see what value AI adds to Stack Overflow other than keeping up with the Joneses. If I want to use AI, I can already do that, by asking ChatGPT directly. I'm here for human answers. All we need is basically a dumb CRUD app. But unfortunately, basic features like [tag leaderboard pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427624/the-tag-scores-have-stopped-updating) are down for 3 weeks and counting, as the company wastes time pursuing random AI initiatives that haven't materialized into any value for the site.

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike *"I don't think I've ever heard a single statement so out of touch with reality before"* agreed, but that is pretty much what I think about whatever is being said about AI by anyone; mister Ryan Polk is simply doing the trendy thing like so many others. Everyone keeps pretending AI already exists. That should become the new definition for hubris.

Comment: Is this post really appropriate for this site? It doesn't seem to have much to do with Stackoverflow - in fact it really seems to just be an advertisement that abuses the featured tag to increase views on Ryan's post.

Comment: Amusingly, no one ever reads the blog, and in the previous bad old days (TM) I was creating the equivalent of this on MSE cause the people who ran the company wouldn't.  Posting here is actually a good thing

Comment: @jla I think it's fine. It hints toward changes to the platform. It may be vague, but I appreciate a heads up even if it's vague so I can kind of sort of mentally brace myself for the worst (I hesitated to write that, since it seems extremely negative, but wrote it anyways since it was honest)

Comment: AI as community members... what horror is that? I actually feel like I need to write an answer here because voting is not enough to express the feeling. StackOverflow may be in for another rough year.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution a good faith reading would remove the *"itself"* and leave *"part of the community"* like: reviewing, voting, content quality and any other thing that not being a part of the community characterizes us metaphorically. I'm always in favor of literary freedom and don't do readings too literally... But in this case the choice of subject being controversial, coming in the wake of recent turmoil, being the over hyped fashion it is, ah well... I give the CTO a thumbs up for (...?) writing! Yes! Writing is important! I like someone who writes.

Comment: @jla that would be the equivalent of someone saying to you "Is that really appropriate for this house?" - when you're in your own living room dancing and singing in your underwear with a VR set on. You do what you want to in your own house even if other people are not allowed to do so by your own rules.

Comment: The North Star is only visible from the Northern Hemisphere ... https://www.skyatnightmagazine.com/advice/southern-hemisphere-cheat-sheet

Comment: In year 2000, whoever said "IT" the most times won a price. Because there was no doubt that "information technology" and the Internet was the future. And yet in year 2002, whoever said "IT" the most times got fired. What did we learn from that? Absolutely nothing, but here are the good news: Whoever says "AI" the most times wins a price!

Comment: Not necessarily - it was crypto before but thankfully all we suffered from was a bunch of sites for it, rather than full scale tulip fever

Comment: I'm guessing the chance of Mr. Polk seeing any of the feedback in here is about the same as the rest of the leaderships has been?

Comment: @Sayse, When I met with him, as I left, he was reading through the feedback here.  So he has actually seen it (at least, that which was posted to that point.  I don't know if he's been back since, but I suspect he has.)

Comment: Stack Overflow's unique value proposition is the *expert* answers by people who really understand the subjects, not some spicy auto-complete. If the company can't see that and understand it pretty soon it's going to kill the goose that laid the golden egg for them...

Comment: But for whom is the egg golden? The current owners or the previous ones who walked away with something around 1.8 billion?

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike "I don't think I've ever heard a single statement so out of touch with reality before" - on the contrary, I am quite confident that the company *does* believe exactly what was said, so the statement is perfectly in touch with the reality of the company's mindset.

Comment: Ah, no wonder they didn't put the topic of the blog post in the sidebar ...

Comment: @starball the only thing that strikes me as noteworthy is that [the previous CPO's posts were hugely popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A704608+%5Bannouncement%5D) and didn't require another staff member to post them. I read that fact as a general deterioration in communication.

Comment: The decision to post it here was mine.  The reasoning is that so far we've only built or deployed anything for AI to Stack Overflow, so it didn't have network impact.  The 5 rep issue wasn't a factor.

Comment: @Philippe I vaguely remember there being an announcement post on MSE within the past couple months where I commented asking why is was posted on MSE instead of MSO, and the answer was something about increasing visibility. but maybe my memory is just corrupted.

Comment: Featured meta post with content posted elesewhere surely deserves downvote. I am *not* reading SO blogs, it has lots of issues. You want to inform me, you already did with featured post, but if you want me to read something, please post it here as a part of the post.

Comment: @Philippe I'm sorry for being pushy, but a friendly reminder: You've [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394117/353058) two [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394772/353058) tagged `community-vp-questions`, promised to read/respond, and here we are several months later, still waiting for responses.

Comment: @Philippe as vaguely a representative of an average power user of the rest of the network - there's always knock on effects, positive or negative from what's done on SO.  So while the AI products are SO only, the impact success or failure has, and the lessons learnt or unlearnt have repercussions for all of us. There's always network impact

Comment: @TravisJ "Why didn't Ryan post this himself?" Directly interacting with the community has gone a bit out of fashion here. Maybe we aren't the intended target audience. Or maybe people inside of SO don't want to use their own product.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution no... it's because whenever they do the result is 200 downvotes (142 and counting so far) and a mountain of critique :) It has been said in the past that employees are actually anxious to post anything on meta due to the response it tends to get.

Comment: @Gimby I guess you're right. Although they could ignore it or not take it personally or take it as a challenge or take it as additional information or introduce a new post type without a score on the question. It also wasn't thought like this. Agreement/disagreement voting was thought to only take place on feature proposals not on discussions.

Comment: @Gimby Actual good news wouldn't be amiss. I can think of a few things the company could/isn't doing that would be well received

Comment: Can you fail anymore than what has already happened so far?  My lord these guys just do NOT get it.

Comment: I participate as a senior dev in order to directly help junior devs. I'm not really interested in helping AI billionaires or to "ensure the success of AI's future".

Comment: Are there any plans for a response to the feedback you invited?

Comment: Hmm, guess that's  "NO". Thanks.

Answer (score 131):

I feel that to be accepted by the community, we need a little more than "It's the future, honest!"

I'm a [former moderator on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393795/im-stepping-down-as-a-meta-moderator-in-response-to-recent-actions-by-the-com) and a current moderator on *[Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)*. In general - AI companies have not shown social responsibility at all - ranging from widespread plagiarism - [locking in content created by the commons into black boxes even they don't understand](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2024/01/openai-says-its-impossible-to-create-useful-ai-models-without-copyrighted-material/), to a replacing [jobs with AI to increase profits](https://arstechnica.com/google/2024/01/google-lays-off-hundreds-more-as-ad-division-switches-to-ai-powered-sales/#p3).

> Now is not the time for moving fast and breaking things because the people left fixing the broken things are the developers.

Well, in the context of the community, its the moderators, and community team, and quite a lot has broken over the last few months and years.

In the context of the Stack Exchange family, we've lost many voices in the company that spoke for us - multiple CMs and Devs who were close to the community. We've also lost core community members - many of whom probably could have helped bridged ties.

The reaction from the community - of people who *contribute* to the knowledge and commons about [AI has been fairly heavily weighted towards it not being a net benefit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). We even had [a strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390106/moderation-strike-update-data-dumps-choosing-representatives-gpt-data-and-wh) over how SO inc tried to handle *our* content in an attempt to deal with GenAI.

Stack Exchange the sites and chat *are* a product and what *should* be funneling people into things. They're often neglected, and kicked aside for other products. You wouldn't have [OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/) without Stack Overflow, and frankly the rest of the network often gets ignored completely, despite us serving a wider, more inclusive audience. Healthy, *happy* communities also mean better more constructive feedback.

Speaking of broken - chat covers much of what [Discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426107/discussions-experiment-launching-on-nlp-collective) could be, and I'm told discussions as it is has a very broken moderation system.

> Stack Overflow is now on a journey to create a new era in the practice of AI: the era of social responsibility. As we prioritize the continued growth of Stack Overflow for Teams accelerated by our GenAI offering, OverflowAI, the addition of time-saving new experiences on the Stack Overflow public platform through OverflowAI, and the expansion of our strategic partnerships—it is all through the lenses of developer flexibility, data quality/accuracy, and community attribution.

If you wish to be socially responsible, it needs to start here. I believe the company talked about putting in 10% of developer time into GenAI (shortly followed by a large scale retrenchment of about 20% of staff).

Social responsibility needs to start at taking care of the community, and our needs. We've traditionally had deep ties and a large proportion of staff who were active in the community - but with actions over the last decade, that trust is lost. I would think social responsibility and showing we can trust your directions starts there.

I guess GenAI is the next shiny, but what about the [things that were ignored?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391832/what-are-some-deferred-ignored-or-sunset-projects-we-wish-se-would-work-on-to)

Under your predecessor, we had a fairly positive relationship with the company. She put resources where we needed them and got the community team rebuilt. I figured, given time and resources, we *were* going in a decent direction before the recent pivot to GenAI.

We have never been a community of bots and AI. With our community cores, it’s always about people and mutual help. I've learnt a lot from the people who *used* to be on SE and left due to all sorts of reasons - many of which were a result of the company not acting in a socially responsible manner and understanding our needs.

We've always been a community of people with common interests.  We've had, unfortunately people who never really understood that, and assumed we were really a Q&A site duct taped to, over time, a job site ([SO Careers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/jobs/info)), a [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) service ([Teams](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/#specific-plans)) and later on whatever the AI plan is. We're communities of enthusiasts and experts who do Q&A. I mean, would I mind having a Q&A tool at a future job? I'd love it, but I'm not sure I'd put in a good word for SE in the current shape and form of things.

I get the feeling that y'all are out of touch with *our* needs. We need solid working communities *first*, and an AI is *never* going to be a community. At best, it’s a tool, at worst, a drain on resources.

If you want to be socially responsible, start with *these* communities. Understand their needs and what makes them unhappy. Give folks the tools we need to mend broken trust, and our communities. GenAI does *nothing* for social responsibility.

Comment: You make lots of good points, but "Under your predecessor, we had a fairly positive relationship" seems like a stretch. I'm assuming you mean Teresa (there was no "VP of Community" before Philippe) - her tenure had the Monica situation as well as many other incidents, e.g. lots of friction between the community and a former Director of Public Q&A who shall not be named. I'm pretty critical of SE in general but would argue some things actually got _better_since then (and of course others got worse and overall it's still bad). But maybe the situation is looking different from a mod perspective.

Comment: @l4mpi Teresa joined SE *after* the Monica debacle (early 2020) and actively worked towards rebuilding the relationship with the community. See [The company’s commitment to rebuilding the relationship with you, our community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343890). IMO, Teresa brought the right kind of change from the side of the company. However, initiatives she started did eventually just stop. For example the roadmaps (see [Please bring back the Community Roadmap posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395503))

Comment: Theresa took over at rock bottom as CPO - while I don't agree with many of the choices made, on the whole she left the community/company relationship in a better place. While I don't remember *everything* and there's probably a good many things that skipped my radar, I try to keep the details mostly straight - not from the perspective of a moderator, but rather someone who probably cares a little too much about the community as it was, as, and ought to be ;)

Comment: Right, seems like I misremembered the timing - Teresa joined roughly a month after the legal agreement between SE and Monica, although that situation was still the main topic at that point in time. I don't quite agree with her "bringing the right kind of change" as I mostly remember meta posts filled with good intentions and hot air, and ultimately nothingburgers - which might of course not be her fault but attributable to company politics. Still, the community relationship with the company was heavily damaged at this point and even though band-aids were deployed trust was never restored.

Comment: "We're communities of enthusiasts and experts who do Q&A" - if only. But perhaps Codidact will fare better in the long run.

Answer (score 121):

> If, instead, individuals interacted with AIs like they were any other community member, transparently collaborating, building, and contributing knowledge, the entire community benefits.

This is not a symmetric relationship; it's an abusive relationship.

AI tools can be used to create massive amounts of content with little to no supervision or effort. Curation of that content is a huge human effort that cannot be performed by automated tools. Worse, content provided by AI tools is rarely identified as such so that the real humans involved do not have a choice whether to opt-in or opt-out. **This is understood to be the major risk of GenAI to society**. This isn't a secret, and anyone paying attention to AI is aware of this. The worry is not a [Skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator)#Cultural_impact)-style human-killing AI; it's production of AI content to an extent that the real humans can't filter it out from real information, whether it's propaganda from state-level actors, falsified reviews and other content to push commercial products, or just inept programming advice. This is a danger for GenAI itself, too, since these models are trained on the very types of data that AI is now being used to create.

Comment: "*Curation of that content is a huge human effort that cannot be performed by automated tools.*" what's more, it can't even be wholly performed by humans. Because the tooling falls short, is inadequate, or *completely missing* for a lot of work that needs to be done.

Comment: Funny thing is this brings to mind [The user never gives anything back to the community, but only takes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) GenAI takes our content, sticks it in a blender, and the stuff that comes out isn't always usable.

Comment: This is a legitimate concern but not a new one and not unique to AI. The US government has been operating fake social media accounts for years. Just one of many examples: https://www.cbsnews.com/news/so-why-does-the-air-force-want-hundreds-of-fake-online-identities-on-social-media-update/

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Of course, but AI tools allow it to be done at scale with minimal cost.

Comment: @BryanKrause I don't see a gain for the propagandists, though. The average person is already fully convinced by a simple press release blaming Russia.

Answer (score 89):

> AIs will become another member of the community—and the community can
> decide the quality, accuracy, and value of their contributions.

No.

Check out [the definitions in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/community) or [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community). You see words and phrases like "social unit", "group of living things", "shared socially significant characteristic", "people with common interests", "body of persons", "interacting population of various kinds of individuals (such as species)". Tools are not part of a community. The community is only the people.

I think it's wrong to ignore AI. It can unlock some new possibilities for how people interact with each other and [artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(archaeology)) they produce, where "artifacts" in the context of Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Network include questions, answers, comments, discussions, articles, chat messages.

People, however, must come first. And I see a potential glimmer of hope when you talk about onboarding and engaging the users - the people that generate and consume content - across the Network. However, this needs to take precedence over "the AI focus".

> Developers need tools and resources to produce quality, safe, and
> secure products, while enterprises need to trust the tools and
> resources to not introduce risk to their business.

This is key.

Your own 2023 Developer Survey [revealed that over 25% of developers do not trust the accuracy of the output of AI tools](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/#section-developer-tools-accuracy-of-ai-tools). Although large numbers of respondents do [see potential benefits of](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/#section-developer-tools-benefits-of-ai-tools) and [have favorable sentiments toward](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/#section-sentiment-and-usage-ai-tool-sentiment) such tools. [A recent ACM TechBrief cites a study out of the University of Queensland and KPMG Australia that found over 60% of people globally do not trust AI](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3641524).

I'm honestly not sure what angle I want to take here - as someone interested and involved in technology ethics, as an expert on tool qualification who is also involved in build and buy decisions, as a member of the Stack Exchange community and a moderator on two Network sites. From all of these angles, I don't see things coming out of the company that demonstrate the ability to help developers with quality or help enterprises reduce risk. In fact, I see the opposite. I see decisions or thinking that is actively harmful to trusting not only the content on the Network, but making it more difficult to have organizations that I have more trust in build trustworthy tools.

And this goes back to needing a people-centric focus. Human people need to be at the heart of every decision. But it seems like trying to cram "AI" everywhere because it's a buzzword is what's really at the heart of company decision making. And that's going to lead to a lack of trust in the product and, more importantly, the data.

Comment: So they want AI to become a part of community, huh? I use ChatGPT daily in my work and it's a cool instrument. But there is a huge difference of communicating with tool or with a colleague. The day, when AI can validate his own answers to prove their correctness, I will change my mind, but as of now AI must have a human supervision. We don't want to have here a bunch of meaningless posts or another queue to handle.

Answer (score 79):

It feels like Stack Overflow is frantically trying to find excuses to introduce AI into the site, just because "everyone does it and it's the next big thing". Like FOMO. Did we exchange badges for NFTs in January 2022? Did we encode our answers in a blockchain in January 2018? No, because there was no need to use those technologies within the site. Should we add AI features to Stack Overflow in January 2024?

AI can be a useful tool for programming, there's no denying that. Making it easy to access and use for everyone interested might be a good and reasonable goal. But where is Stack Overflow in that equation? **Must** it be in there? Or could Stack Overflow just be a *different* tool or rather resource to make programming easier? Could Stack Overflow remain to be the **alternative** to generated code?

> Roses in the dust
> Violets on the road
> Programming is more than
> Generating code

<sup>Taken and adapted from a YouTube comment by "freecodecamp" from Tom Scott's video on "The consequences of your code"</sup>

Rather than treating AI integration as prerequisite, and then tinkering with ideas and ways to achieve that, I suggest to think about what the community (that is us, in case you forgot) *actually* needs and wants, and start doing that. If AI can help with that, fine. But if not, then maybe don't use it?

Image generation sucked until the invention of GANs. Then GANs got better and better in their niches, until they hit the crest of their splinter skill mountain. Yet it was not until the advent of Stable Diffusion that we had truly universally capable image generation.

I think it's entirely possible that the current approach of LLMs is the next GAN. Vastly superior compared to all we had before, but ultimately still flawed in its approach to the problem and not useful enough to solve it. We might find ourselves starting from scratch after realizing we've hit a dead-end that was still "not good enough". Maybe, by building increasingly larger LLMs to overcome halucination, we are building bigger and bigger rockets to overcome launch cost, when all we needed was re-usability.

Personally, I think generative AI is a tool that humanity hasn't even fully understood yet, let alone mastered. And striving for "mastery" now, with proclaimed noble goals such as "socially responsible usage", seems like a premature move on "our" side of the product. The ability to trace sources of generated results as well as prevention of hallucinated results has to come from within the technology itself. It cannot be outsourced to a few poor volunteers who, hour after hour, weed through content that can be generated within seconds.

GenAI output is already contributing to fake news. Facebook is full of "X made this Y" fake craftsmanship postings. Twitter is full of false claims. Websites are full of engaging stories split into 20 paragraphs on 20 pages to maximize site impressions and clicks. Only telling in the fine print that the story is fictional and provided for entertainment purposes. "News" sites, even reputable ones, are putting out false stories as facts, and their efforts of tidying up later are lackluster at best.

The Internet is dangerously ill. Creating, publishing and spreading anything untrue - AI generated or not - takes a fraction of the time that it takes to rectify it. And while we can maybe laugh at many of the faked photos, we probably won't laugh at hallucinated code that ended up in critical infrastructure.

So please, don't act as if AI was ready to be released into the world, and don't think you can reasonably enforce quality in a system that has no reliable quality control in its design principles yet.

The AI providers claim "Please use with care, may generate wrong answers." Stack Overflow's processes have been designed over the years to avoid having a  need for this claim on its own answers. But once we allow AI content in its current state to flood the page, Stack Overflow loses that advantage.

Comment: Indeed. The analogy is going to be programmers of the near future. There are going to be those that will be programming through a variety of ChatGippity and/or copilot and then there are those, the Cobol programmers of the "AI"-age, who do old school development, using old school knowledge, skill and cunning to solve problems requiring a brain rather than an algorithm. Stack Overflow is part of the Cobol crowd, not the "AI" crowd. Unless it completely reinvents itself, which at this point I am shocked it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: I would also like to point out that when I say "LLMs may not be useful enough to solve the problem" I am talking specifically about code. LLMs are good at generating text, but code isn't "text". It's an accurate recipe, where understanding the exact difference between 1 and 2 is important. LLMs predict what is _likely_ to be next. But code is at its core mathematical instructions on bits, and _likely_ isn't good enough, it must be **right**. For LLMs, we just the hope that the truth has been predominant in the training data and it was transferred into becoming the most likely prediction.

Comment: "what the community actually needs and wants" - ah, but AI is the community now, so they just ask ChatGPT what it wants and do that.

Comment: @OrangeDog That is why I included the "that is us", which reads spiteful, but is actually an honest clarification. GenAI tools are nothing like us. We usually realize when we don't know an answer and subsequently actually don't write one. But AI will always give an answer, one that likely _feels_ right at first glance. But we can only **hope** that is because it _is_ - but no guarantees. AI could always post iffy answers instantly. Their contributions cannot be treated equally, as our answers mostly come from knowledge, and where the authoring itself is already a proof of work.

Answer (score 74):

The "north star" metaphor has been [twisted and abused for so long now](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151103-00/?p=91861) that it may be naive to expect any meaning at all from words found in its vicinity... But for the sake of discussion,

> Our north star is offering a true collaboration between the individual, AIs, and a global community — working in unison to solve problems, save time/frustration for developers, and speed up innovation responsibly. Now is not the time for moving fast and breaking things because the people left fixing the broken things are the developers.

I'll translate:

> Our guiding principle is slow and deliberate facilitation of information transfer between individual developers, developers as a group, and some well-funded databases built from the work of the former whose future value might be jeopardized if access to future work gets more difficult.

I'll contrast this with [the original principle which drove the creation of Stack Overflow](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/):

> by programmers, for programmers, with the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world.

Now, times change and so do stars; just as the star that points north in our sky today is not the same one that our long-ago ancestors navigated by, so it is with these metaphorical "stars". What matters isn't the mass of gas, but where following it leads...

Answer (score 57):

> In 2024, we’re looking at how we can continue to enable developers and technologists by welcoming AIs into our ecosystem and providing paths for everyone to collaborate with AIs. Our alpha testers are trying out an early experiment, conversational search, and we’re looking at doing more. AIs will become another member of the community—and the community can decide the quality, accuracy, and value of their contributions.

I certainly hope that it won't become part of this community. Stack Overflow is, and should remain, a site by humans and for humans. I come to Stack Overflow for information generated and vetted by humans. If I really wanted ChatGPT hallucinations.. err... "answers", I can easily go to ChatGPT myself; it's unclear what value Stack Overflow would be adding in this case.

Comment: Yep, on SO [agent Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Smith) has taken the form of ChatGPT answers. We could say they're around.

Answer (score 40):

> and we’re looking at doing more. AIs will become another member of the community—and the community can decide the quality, accuracy, and value of their contributions.

If you're considering introducing AI involvement to curation or answer-post-generation, I invite you to please first read the following posts of mine:

- [My answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388418/997587)- especially at the part that starts with "*you've got to (not really, but it sure would be nice if you'd) talk with us and think real hard about [...]*"
- [My answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391147/997587) to [If SE introduces system-generated answers, how to fit them into SE's question and answers model](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391073/997587).
- [Didn't the title and formatting assistants violate OpenAI's policy for Sharing and Publication?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425540/11107541)
- [How could AI be used to augment curation tooling?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389744/997587-) with emphasis on the last bullet point
- [Is the cost of ChatGPT integration into Stack Exchange sustainable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390305/997587)
- [My answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390246/997587) to [Is there a correlation between opposing the use of AI-generated content on Stack Exchange and rating AI low in general?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390228/997587)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/384378/2 around the section "*My Closing Unsolicited Personal Thoughts: Do AI belong here on SE?*" (this was written against individual person-operated users posting AI answers

Please think hard about the design questions I raise in those posts, and involve us in your thinking process.

To summarize my personal feelings, I'm apprehensive of that direction.

---

> Now is not the time for moving fast and breaking things because the people left fixing the broken things are the developers.

Wow.

- [The tag scores have stopped updating](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427624/11107541)
- [Top users not updated for about a month](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427636/11107541)
- [Error when clicking calendar view for daily visits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426239/11107541)
- [AI search: sometimes returning no results, toggling off takes hours, opting back in days instead of instant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427201/11107541)
- [Questions and Articles are occasionally duplicated into two identical posts created in the same instant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427072/11107541)
- [The Cookie Policy link is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396105/997587)
- [Cookie pop-ups are repeatedly displayed on international sites & translations are not reflected and displayed in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396179/997587)
- [New activity indicator (bullet/dot) in Custom Filters no longer displaying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383520/997587)
- [Why is the URL advanced search operator only finding lowercase URLs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393124/997587)

Answer (score 4):

Sentence #1:

> As a company, we strongly believe that the community of the world’s most engaged developers and technologists and the answers they share will ensure the success of AI’s future.

Eh, I was more hoping for "we strongly believe that AI will ensure the success of the community of the world's most engaged &c".

Doesn't the sentence as stated say "we will sponge off the community of developers to develop AI"?

Answer (score 1):

The aftermath of every scam Kickstarter is pretty much the same: dozens sometimes hundreds of the same comment where the poor sods tries to invoke their rights under a ToC which has not been in effect over a decade. Of course no one from Kickstarter ever reads these or even if they do they certainly don't care.

So it is here.

Ever since the company decided to walk down the dark path, set a well known corporate butcher as CEO who, as could be expected, fired CMs and probably a lot more people we do not know about then sold to a private company -- and be happy it's not a corporate raider I guess they didn't see much value in it -- no one reads or cares what you post here. Y'all made it clear you want no AI on the site which is ignored. Yeah there's a ban on AI generated answers but that's a trivial concession which cost the company nothing. But the search is now AI powered and so on and so on. You can't stop the enshittification by complaining. It doesn't work.

The Reddit community tried to strike. It didn't work. Eventually the company told the moderators to open up or be replaced and most relented. By now it's quite clear nothing has changed over there.

The big twitter exodus has seen ... Mastodon exploding to a full 3% of the twitter userbase. *Yay*.

This place ostensibly has a lot of damn smart people. So instead of complaining try to find a better solution. The dump of the data is available so perhaps stand up a competitor and organize a mass move over? Of course these sites will always be higher in Google and there will always be power hungry trolls who will gladly put on the moderator hats so these sites won't die at all. But perhaps, eventually, a better alternative for monetization could be found and the new sites could flourish.

Comment: Complaining is cheaper than investing money and time to make something better. There is inbuilt inertia. But still, just imagine power users were fully standing behind the mission, motivated and answering questions or handling tons of flags day in and day out. Part of why SO had to lay off employees is surely because they couldn't sell their current ideas that well to their user base. Sometimes we all have to live with a suboptimal solution.

Answer (score -1):

The future of AI: help develop AI or you’ll be laid off, and after you help develop AI you’ll be laid off.

Comment: Looks a bit like it. How does it feel to only be the delivery guy of some training text for the AI instead of directly interacting with other humans. I asked that already [How do content authors feel about AI powered searches using their content for summaries?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425855/how-do-content-authors-feel-about-ai-powered-searches-using-their-content-for-su)

Comment: Too many people, not enough robots. It's a basic problem.

Answer (score -7):

Responsible AI is important.    I have found that using AI tools daily has changed the way I ask questions.   It feels more natural.   The current AI search that is being tested on SO is very well thought out.  It gives references to all the source information on the response.   Allowing me to see it in a context that helps me see my unique case more specifically.

Credit and Attribution are critical elements of SO.  In addition to the references to questions.    Maybe a hit counter on number of times a question is referenced in an AI Response, and new Badges to still help acknowledge good questions and Answers.

For those concerned about source data and false answers, if that data is from SO then it's already been curated and ranked by voting and accepted answers.
If an AI generated response to a query is returns a wrong answer it's really no different than when I find a question/answer that looks like it would help but does not.

So the current AI All this basically does is it allow SO to help you find data quickly.

Imagine AI prompting for correct TAGS when asking a question.   Or alerting a person is asking that the question is incomplete and could use some additional data to ask a question that can be answered.

Also Off-topic alerts to the asker of the question could happen and redirect them to the correct SE site.

All of this leads to people getting answers to questions faster.

Comment: "_If an AI generated response to a query is returns a wrong answer it's really no different than when I find a question/answer that looks like it would help but does not._" - no. because current "AI" do not have actual understanding, they can more easily "interpret" a question or context wrong, and give information that does not fit the context or the question.

Comment: "All of this leads to people getting answers to questions faster." Faster yes. Good answers that are actually helpful and improve the productivity? The jury is still out. I've made good and bad experience with AI so far. The same goes for SO, but there I would still say that I profit more from a combination of google and experts giving spot on answers to difficult problems. AI is currently mostly helping me in avoiding and speeding up repetitive tasks. The clue is how SO and AI get combined. To the better or worse. We'll see.